# Hello world doesn't run in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I have worked many years with Eclipse. After decided try IntelliJ Idea. Bua also simple java Hello World doesn't run! It is simply happens nothing. What should I check/adjust?
Thanks.

```
package test; 
/** * Created with IntelliJ IDEA. 
    * Date: 16/06/12 
    * Time: 12:13 
    * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates. 
*/ 
public class Main { 
    public static void main(String ...args)
       { System.out.println("Hello World"); } 
}
```

Comment: Well... what exactly happens when you try to run it? Some more information would be nice. What code are you trying to run?

Comment: Nothing. After I have press green arrow - nothing. May be something happens in backgroung - but I don't know where.

Comment: Can you post the code you are trying to run?

Comment: package test;

/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * Date: 16/06/12
 * Time: 12:13
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
public class Main {
    public static void main(String ...args){
       System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}

Comment: I found on my shared disk this folder: .IdeaIC11. Does it can be the reason shared network disk?

Comment: Happens only that green arrow changed colore to grey, but I don't see any output.

Comment: Well I've never actually used Intellij-Idea, but you could try checking this video out, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4zKWO8sqnVc

Comment: You can also change logging settings into bin/log.xml to retrieve some useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of problem with shared network disk.
If default user folder on shared network disk IntelliJ will not work correct. 
Find idea.properties and fix paths don't use shared network disk

Comment: OH MY GOD. Thank you for solving this for me after HOURS of banging my head!

Comment: How can I fix that??