# How to set IntelliJ Idea to run simple java application?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hello world doesn't run in IntelliJ Idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062972/hello-world-doesnt-run-in-intellij-idea)

I am newbe for IntelliJ idea, so I try from HelloWorld:

```
 package test;

 /**
  * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
  * Date: 16/06/12
  * Time: 12:13
  * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
  */
 public class Main {
     public static void main(String ...args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
     }
 }
```

But this program doesn't run! Only green arrow getting grey, but I don't see any output.
Which setting I should check?
Thanks.
Compiler:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Right click on the `main` function name and select Debug

[image: Creating configuration]

The "green arrow" just runs the current configuration, when the above right clicking creates such. You can create and customize the configurations with the `Edit Configurations` button, to the left.

[image]

Comment: I think the problem is in settings.

Answer (score 2):

I found the reason - folder .IdeaIC was installed in my home directory that on network disk.
After I have changed in properties ides.properties to use folder on local disk - all run well!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at debugging with Intelij, [jetbrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/debug-tool-window.html).

Command 5 to open debug menu or view->tool windows->debug

Comment: I don'w know why - but debug is disabled.

Comment: What operating system are you on? is the java runtime installed?

Comment: Makes sure your compiler to use is set to javac, as the IDE supports many

Comment: yes, installation has only option for select directory