# Run the current file in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I've recently tried to switch from Eclipse to IntelliJ as a debugger for my university course, and I'm really enjoying the auto-completion, Chronon backwards debugging and other nice features. But there's one thing that bugs the living hell out of me: I just want to run the current file!

In Eclipse, the "Run" button was intelligent enough to simply run the current file if it contained a main method, and use the last-ran file otherwise. But in IntelliJ, just running a file is much more complicated. You have to create a Run Configuration of the right file, and then select that Run Configuration, instead of just opening the file you want. This is a big hassle for me, especially since I have many different classes with main methods in most homeworks and projects.

I found that on Macs, Ctrl + FN + Shift + F10 will "Run Context Configuration", which is almost what I'm looking for. But for some reason, this key binding doesn't have an equivalent toolbar button that switches to the context configuration and just runs it, which would solve all my problems! Can anyone help me out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set IntelliJ Idea to run simple java application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063115/how-to-set-intellij-idea-to-run-simple-java-application)

Comment: I've seen that question and its possible duplicate, but no satisfactory answers over there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Years later, the simple answer: Right click inside the file and hit "Run"!

Comment: The hotkey for this is ctrl + shift + f10 on windows. So shift + f10 to run the current run configuration, ctrl + shft + f10 to run current file.

Comment: useful for me.But I still want a macro as the argument

Answer (score 10):

I can't find a "Run current file, otherwise selected context" action. I did find them separately.

Key binds for "Run current file":

- Run context configuration
- Debug context configuration

Answer (score 7):

If you hover over the `Run` and `Debug` buttons you'll see the shortcuts. Given you're on a Mac OS and `Fn` is important to trigger F buttons here's the shortcuts:

**Run**: `Shift` + `Fn` + `F10`

**Debug**: `Shift` + `Fn` + `F9`

Comment: Hi! I attempted the shortcuts, but they only apply to the current run configuration, and not the currently open file.

Comment: But you can't run without the context configuration.. On Mac OS triggering a file to run (with main() method) without a context configuration (it will create one) is what you were doing: Ctrl + FN + Shift + F10

Comment: I suppose Ctrl + FN + Shift + F10 pretty much does what I was looking for. I'm irked that there's no toolbar button for it, but I'll rebind it to something simpler.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, Mark Jernonimus's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36259806/1399811) is better

Answer (score 4):

Did this change since the original question? In 2018 on Mac I just do `ctrl + r` to re-run the last run file and `ctrl + shift + r` to run the current file.

Comment: This is the answer in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

**@dimitrisli** answer was partially correct.

In fact, if you want to run the current script you need to use:

```
CONTROL + FN + SHIFT + F10
```

`FN + SHIFT + F10` => runs the last execution

(but if you add CONTROL it will run the current script if the file has a main method or is a test class).

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `Run` and `Debug` buttons run the last configuration. If you want to run the current file, right click in the editor and you'll see entries to run or debug the current file.

On Windows, I have `Alt`+ `Shift` + `F6` to run a Java or JS file and `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `F5` to debug (using the Netbeans keymap).

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X: IntelliJ Idea:

`control(^) +  shift + r` => Runs current file.

*Bonus:*

1. Press `Cmd + 1` to shift focus to the project structure
2. Navigate to the file in question using arrow keys
3. `control + shift + r` to run the file

Answer (score 0):

I think, [@dimitrisli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44858844/21264531) has still the correct answer:
In IntelliJ on a Mac, If you want to run the current open file you can press
`control` + `shift` + `R`

In addition: your focus should be in the file you want to run (you see the cursor blinking in the active file). But you can quickly jump into the editor by hitting `Esc`

Besides, IntelliJ provides you a list of shortcuts when you press `command` + `shift` + `A` and then begin to write what you want to do (e.g. "run").

Answer (score 0):

After NetBeans, I was surprised that IntelliJ compiles all project files for the DEBUG only one Java file. So to run a single file I had to complete all the files.